# Automatically 'refreshing' the woocommerce's shopping cart when programmatically adding to a cart

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress, woocommerce

I am using woocommerce in wordpress.

I am showing the shopping cart in one of my pages using the following :

```
 <div id="shopping-cart"><?php echo do_shortcode('[woocommerce_cart]');?></div>
```

I am adding a product to this cart using my own function when a user clicks a button by using this code:

```
 function addToCart(p_id){
     alert("Adding to cart:"+p_id);
      jQuery.get('/wordpress/?post_type=product&add-to-cart=' + p_id, function(response) {
             // call back
             alert(response);
          });

         //jQuery("#shopping-cart").append("[woocommerce_cart]"); 
           alert("Added to cart:"+p_id);
    }
```

I am calling this javascript by the following code :

```
 <button type="button" onclick="return addToCart(18);">Add to cart</button>
```

The code works but the cart created using the do_shortcode does not update after the ajax request completes.

Can somebody please tell me how to make the cart update automatically when the get request completes?

Comment: How about using "location.reload" in one of the callbacks? like "done" ?

Comment: no - that does not work, as it causes the ENTIRE page to refresh - which looses context of the cart process and therefore looses my cart etc -- The product add obviously still works, but you only see it then by processing forward several steps again.

Answer (score 1):

[Documentation](http://docs.woothemes.com/document/show-cart-contents-total/) to the rescue :)

```
// Ensure cart contents update when products are added to the cart via AJAX (place the following in functions.php)
add_filter('add_to_cart_fragments', 'woocommerce_header_add_to_cart_fragment');

function woocommerce_header_add_to_cart_fragment( $fragments ) {
    global $woocommerce;
    ob_start();
?>
<a class="cart-contents" href="<?php echo $woocommerce->cart->get_cart_url(); ?>" title="<?php _e('View your shopping cart', 'woothemes'); ?>"><?php echo sprintf(_n('%d item', '%d items', $woocommerce->cart->cart_contents_count, 'woothemes'), $woocommerce->cart->cart_contents_count);?> - <?php echo $woocommerce->cart->get_cart_total(); ?></a>
<?php
    $fragments['a.cart-contents'] = ob_get_clean();
    return $fragments;
}
```

You'll probably need to tweak the HTML to suit your design.

Comment: Hey yeah I found that - but I have no idea how to integrate it into my code.

Comment: Just add the code to functions.php and that should do the trick.

Comment: which functions.php file!?

Comment: Your theme's functions.php file  `/wp-content/themes/your-theme/functions.php`

Comment: Ok...done that and it made no difference to the cart being displayed using do_shortcode('woocommerce_cart')

Answer (score 0):

In the end I create an Ajax call which called a PHP function which returned the result of calling do_shortcode('[woocommerce_cart]'); which I then simply put into the same div after emptying it - works nicely :)

I had to use Ajax through woocommerce to actually get the do_shortcode call in the PHP to run successfully as per :

http://codex.wordpress.org/AJAX_in_Plugins

Answer (score -1):

Try adding this code after the Added to Cart alert...

```
location.reload();
```

Comment: Nice idea ;) but does not work, because the page is knee deep in ajax by this point, on location.reload() the page which loads has no cart because it is back at the pre-purchasing decision point of the user.